# Connector identification for PCB

Tags: pcb, connector, identification

I have been scrolling like a zombie through Digikey, Farnell and Molex websites to identify the reference of this fairly common looking 5 pin connector of a board I am reverse engineering, but couldn't find it yet.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could shorten my sufferings.

[image: Male connector view 1]

[image: Male connector view 2]

[image: Female PCB connector]

Best regards

Comment: It would probably help to edit your question and add outside dimensions and pitch.

Comment: Thanks Jack B, I took a bet that this was a sufficiently mainstream connector so that an experienced EE engineer would recognized it, and it worked. If I need to ask a similar question again, I will include connector metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is almost certainly a JST XH series.  XHP-5 to be precise.

[Digi-Key link.](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/XHP-5/455-2268-ND/1125486)

[image]

These are quite common and can be found in many places.  Just search for "JST XHP-5".

BTW, here are the correct terminals to use: [Digi-Key link](https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/xh-series/9030)

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me able to not spend hours on this topic where I am absolutely not qualified or experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of these:

Manufacturer Part Number:   S5B-XH-A(LF)(SN)
Description:    CONN HEADER R/A 5POS 2.5MM

[image]
Source: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/S5B-XH-A-LF-SN/455-2242-ND/1651040